# My Wi-Fi Network has some weird status I don't know about

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Usually the networks that show up in my Internet connection show that if they are *open*, *secured* or *connected* if I am connected to them.

But today, when I check the Internet connection board, it shows these status instead of the usual ones.

I do not know if this is normal or something interfere with my network or something else. Can someone please help me with this?

[image: Screenshot of recognized WiFi networks]

Comment: It means the NIC is connection to a wireless connection point but no internet.  When this mark shows do you have Internet?

Comment: My laptop still able to connect to the internet normally. But the status of the networks has changed, just like in the picture.

Comment: Strange.  Reinstall the wireless driver to see if that corrects the icons.  Also run dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth from an Admin Command prompt

Comment: I've tried reinstall the driver and run the command but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What does it say when you right click on the network icon in the taskbar and choose `Troubleshoot problems`?

Comment: I just ran Troubleshoot problems, It said: Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings.

Comment: Looks like it's only happening with WiFi networks added by your company's policies. The troubleshooting results suggest it's related to a proxy server specified by a company policy. Try looking at your proxy server settings for more clues. No harm in asking your company's IT department about it - they might not be aware it's happening yet.

Comment: I'm currently staying in University's dormitory with my friends. All of them have normal network status except me. Maybe I will ask about this with my school IT department later. Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the Wireless icon work on other wireless locations (not University)?   Since the other steps did not work, you may now consider trying a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10